Is there a way to implement unit tests on ChampSim?
I'm using ChampSim - an open-source trace based simulator and I have created my own implementations of lfu and fifo.
ChampSim: https://github.com/ChampSim/ChampSim
However, I was wondering if I could create unit tests to check if my implementations are correct? Is there any way I could create unit tests on champsim? If not, how could I possibly check the validity of my implementations? Any suggestions?
I tried to simulate a few cases but I'm fairly new to ChampSim so, I don't really know where to look at.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It is kind of like writing tests for your unit tests, as a simulator is just another analysis tool. You would write low-level tests for an implementation for specific scenarios, e.g. in a caching library, but unlikely on the reference algorithm. When I wrote a simulator, I would verify the policy by running traces, either in their simulator if available or compare with the hit rates reported in their paper. I always wanted to record/replay traces on CI to assert the hit rate stability, but interesting traces are large which is unfriendly.
